# R - dropping columns sequentially in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to write a for loop that drops each column in a data frame and saves the modified data frame to a new variable.

This code illustrates what I would like the loop to perform

```
df1 = df[,-1]
df2 = df[,-2]
df3 = df[,-3]

#failed loop syntax 1 (unexpected "[" in "df[i] = df[,-[")

for (i in 1:3){
   df[i] = df[,-[i]]}

#failed loop syntax 2 (number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length)

for (i in 1:3){
   df[i] = df[,-i]}
```

Can anyone help me with this?
This is an example to illustrate what I would like to achieve. The real data set contains 28 rows and 64 columns. I am trying to see how removing any one of the 64 columns affects the distribution of the 28 items in a K Cluster plot. I've tried PCA plots, but they are relatively useless with the 64 vectors.

## EDIT:

slava-kohut's code (pasted below)worked perfectly for the first problem. Can anyone help me loop the output of the below code into a series of K cluster plots with the data input listed as the plot title?

```
for (i in 1:64){
  assign(paste0(deparse(substitute(mydata)),i),mydata[,-i])
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading my answer at [How to make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) - generally variables named sequentially like that are hard to work with. You'll need to use `assign()` to create them, and `get()` to use them, and bugs are easy to make and hard to find. Can you give a broader context about *why* you want to do this, and perhaps we can recommend a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you want:

```
for (i in 1:3){
  assign(paste0(deparse(substitute(mtcars)),i), mtcars[,-i])
}
```

`assign` will assign a variable in your current environment.

**EDIT**: modifying environments without understanding what exactly is going on can be dangerous and lead to bugs. Why do you want to achieve what you want to achieve?

Comment: Awesome, this did exactly what I was looking for! I edited my initial description to include more details. I have a data set of 28 rows, 64 columns. I would like to generate K cluster plots for the 28 items after removing each column to see the affect of that column on the cluster plot. So I need to generate 64 cluster plots using matrices I just generated. Yes, I've tried PCA plots, but they were useless with the 64 vectors. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider accepting or upvoting if you like the answer. You can generate plots one by one without creating 64 variables.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) data:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=1:5, c=1:5)
```

Using 'lapply':

```
df_list <- lapply(1:3, function(x) df[, -x])
```

Returns:

> ```
> [[1]]
> b c
> 1 1 1
> 2 2 2
> 3 3 3
> 4 4 4
> 5 5 5
>
> [[2]]
> a c
> 1 1 1
> 2 2 2
> 3 3 3
> 4 4 4
> 5 5 5
>
> [[3]]
> a b
> 1 1 1
> 2 2 2
> 3 3 3
> 4 4 4
> 5 5 5
> ```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `sapply`

```
sapply(1:3, function(x) df[, -x])
```